# How to connect to SPARQL endpoint by using RDFSharp?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

I want to use RDFSharp, a library for .net framework to deal with my rdf data stored in GraphDB ontotext server. How can I connect my sparql endpoint by using RDFSharp library?

Comment: I don't why you don't want to continue with dotnetrdf which you already used, but you should ask the devs for documentation: https://github.com/mdesalvo/RDFSharp - it's also not clear what you mean by "connect". The API might not support remote SPARQL over HTTP given that it contains only a memory and a SQL based store.

Comment: OK thanks for you comments. As you mentioned, I am already using Donetrdf for writing services. Whereas I need to submit one small PoC by using RDFsharp. that's why I put the question.

Comment: fair enough. if I were, I'd ask the devs for some docs or example. And whether it's even possible to use a remote SPARQL endpoint. Check the code, there are just two implementations of RDFStore - so maybe it's not possible, but they will know better than me

Answer (score 1):

In the RDFSharp [docs](https://github.com/mdesalvo/RDFSharp/releases/download/v2.1.0/RDFSharp-2.1.0.pdf) it is explained: use the "ApplyToSPARQLEndpoint" method to send your query to your endpoint instance.